# how do i create an if statement that outputs two names of students who have the same number of minutes from csv file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csv, c#-6.0

I am trying to output two names of students who have the same number of mins from a CSV file

input file :

ID,Last Name,First Name,Phone Number,Minutes

1,Doe,John,905-555-5555,1020

2,Barnett,Courtney,905-666-6666,112

3,Morrison,Jim,905-777-7777,912

4,Doe,Jane,905-222-2222,1020

5,Mitchell,Joni,416-333-3333,112

(ignore spaces between each line)

here Courtney and Joni have the same number of minimum minutes...i need to output both their names

my code is:

```
// open input file
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("input.txt");
{
// initialize variables
int x=0,total= 0; double average=0;
string? titles,lastFirst;
string [ ] info, titlesSplit; int [ ] mins= new int [5]; string[,] myName = new string[5,5];

{
titles =sr.ReadLine();
titlesSplit = titles.Split(',');

for (x=0;x < 5; x++)
{
    System.Console.Write(titlesSplit[x] + " ");
}
 System.Console.WriteLine();
 System.Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");

for(x = 0; x < 5 ; x++)
{  
    lastFirst = sr.ReadLine(); 
    info =  lastFirst.Split(',');
    
    for (int k =0; k<5; k ++)
    {
        myName[x,k]= info[k];
    }
}

int maxMin = Int32.MinValue;
int minMin = Int32.MaxValue;

string? maxName = " ";
string? maxLastName = " ";
string? minName=" ";
string? minLastName = " ";

for (int l = 0; l<5; l++)
{
    for (int k =0; k <5;k++)
    {
        System.Console.Write(myName[l,k] + " ");
    }
    System.Console.WriteLine();
    

    if (Convert.ToInt32(myName[l,4]) > maxMin)
    {
        maxMin = Convert.ToInt32(myName[l,4]);
        maxName = myName[l,1];
        maxLastName= myName[l,2];
        //if statement to output two names of students who have the same number of mins 
    }
  
    if(Convert.ToInt32(myName[l,4]) > minMin );
    {
        minMin= Convert.ToInt32(myName[l,4]);
        minName= myName[l,1];
        minLastName= myName[l,2];

        //if statement to output two names of students who have the same number of 
        mins 
     
    }  
      total = (total + Convert.ToInt32(myName[l, 4]));
} 

    average = (total / 5);
    System.Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------");
    System.Console.WriteLine("Minimum: " + minName +" " + minLastName +" " + minMin);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Maximum: " + maxName +" " + maxLastName+ " "+ maxMin);
    System.Console.WriteLine("Average: " + average);

}
    
}

sr.Close();
```

Comment: You need to put the WriteLine code inside the for loop to show more than one results.

Comment: In this case, you can create lists of strings which will represent student names with a maximum and minimum value. If the value in the current iteration equals maximum value that was found so far, you should add the student's name to the corresponding list. However if current value is greater than the maximum value that was found so far you should clear a list and add current student name to empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to change up your code a bit. For example, I think it would be a good idea to create a model class for your line entries:

```
public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public int Minutes { get; set; }

}
```

The code to output the names of the entries, that have the smallest amount of minutes might then look something like this:

```
// open input file
using StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path);

List<Person> Persons = new();

_ = sr.ReadLine(); // ignore first line

while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    var line = sr.ReadLine();
    var values = line!.Split(',');

    Persons.Add(new Person
    {
        ID = int.Parse(values[0]),
        LastName = values[1],
        FirstName = values[2],
        PhoneNumber = values[3],
        Minutes = int.Parse(values[4])
    });
}

foreach(var person in Persons.OrderBy(p => p.Minutes).GroupBy(m => m.Minutes).First())
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.FirstName);
}
```

It might be a good idea to add some more checks for the parsing and if you have big amounts of data, one might look into some performance improvements, but in general this should give some idea.